# Change python version from 3 to 2.7

Tags: python, macos

now my default python version is 3.5

```
python -V
Python 3.5.1
```

How i can reset my default Python version to 2.7?

My os - Mac osx 10.11.4 (15E65)

which python

```
/usr/bin/python
```

echo $PATH

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Comment: Use `/usr/bin/python`. How did you install Python 3.5, using homebrew perhaps?

Comment: Without details like the output of `which python ` and `echo $PATH` or how you installed Python 3.5, this is almost impossible to answer concisely.

Comment: update my question

Comment: You are using a virtualenv. Just run `deactivate`.

Comment: /usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin  AND /usr/bin/python - without virtualenv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you activated a virtualenv. Just run the `deactivate` script:

```
$ deactivate
```